# Компилятор, который не будет оптимизировать код

Tags: c++

Подскажите, а то хочу проверить кое-что, но не могу из-за оптимизации кода компилятором, а самих компиляторов пробовал уже штуки 4.

Comment: Очень не конкретно. Смотря что. А лучше - посмотрите документацию по конкретным компиляторам. Например, у gcc очень много опций компиляции, в том числе и отключающих ту или иную оптимизацию.

Comment: давайте код. может Вы делаете какое-то UB? А там результат может зависеть от фазы Луны.

Comment: Тестировал с помощью этого когда http://pastebin.com/Lnf4CyJk

Comment: Пробовал отключать оптимизацию в MSVC и gcc,но результат всегда был такой:
http://pastebin.com/cmsMa22A
 А мне нужен был такой :
http://pastebin.com/xXHNq7dS
 Вообщем смог этого добится только в онлайн компиляторе http://codepad.org/lbGtgoYw

Comment: Хм, странно, почему код `A a = b;` вызывает `void operator= (const C& c)`. Вроде не должен же?

Comment: Я ещё добавил оператор копирования, вот результат: http://pastebin.com/XfeE84CA

Comment: @VladD А когда должен вызываться оператор `=`?

Comment: @VladD он и не вызывается ;)
@mzrab нумерация строк в приведенном вами коде и в выводе различаются на 1, что в первой строке?  
Как я понял вы ожидаете вызова
    A (const A& a) { DEBUG; }
который и не должен произойти. На каком таком онлайн компиляторе у вас это получилось? Все известные мне онлайн компиляторы ведут себя корректно. http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/01/online-c-compilers

Comment: @alexlz, @Dith: А, точно. Лучше бы ТС выводил не номер строки, а имя функции :)

Comment: [@Dith][1],[Тут][2], выше в сообщении уже указывал. Мне было важно просто проверить теорию и все, а так я понимаю целесообразность такой оптимизации в нынешних компиляторах.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/8139/dith
  [2]: http://codepad.org/lbGtgoYw

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Практический каждый компилятор разрешает отключить оптимизацию.

Например, для gcc используйте ключ `-O0`. (Вот [ссылка](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options) на полную документацию.)

Для MSVC используйте ключ `/Od` или свойства проекта Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Optimizations. (Вот [ссылка](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx) на полную документацию.)

Для остальных компиляторов обратитесь к их документации.

---

Кстати, не все упрощения кода являются оптимизацией. Например, предвычисление константных выражений проводится независимо от ключей оптимизации. Пример:

```
char buffer[sizeof(somestruct) + 1];
```

откомпилируется, выражение `sizeof(somestruct) + 1` будет вычислено во время компиляции, и такое вычисление не считается оптимизацией.